# How to change the video source id of a webRTC stream?

Tags: javascript, react-native, tensorflow, webrtc

Basically I am trying to take the data from the tensorFlow camera, in react native, and send that data through a webRTC stream. Right now the webRTC stream is set to either choose between the front or back camera. Is there a way to send the data from the tensor camera through the rtc connection?

```
    const isFront = true;
const devices = await mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

const facing = isFront ? 'front' : 'environment';
const videoSourceId = devices.find(device => device.kind === 'videoinput' && device.facing === facing);
const facingMode = isFront ? 'user' : 'environment';
const constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: {
    mandatory: {
      minWidth: 500, // Set width, height and frame rate here
      minHeight: 300,
      minFrameRate: 100,
    },
    facingMode,
    optional: videoSourceId ? [{ sourceId: videoSourceId }] : [],
    // is there a way to change this source to the tensor data?
  },
};
```

Comment: what's your issue exactly? are you trying to get the stream from a specific device id?

Comment: You're using outdated constraints syntax. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#parameters). Is your camera listed [here](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/)? If so, you can look for it with `enumerateDevices()` and use `deviceId`.